# How to get which do not intersect value between 2 Array with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, intersection

How to get which do not intersect value between 2 Array with Lodash?

**Expected:**

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
const arr2 = [2, 3, 4]

console.log(unintersection(arr1, arr2))
```

**Output**

```sh
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`_.xor()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#xor) to find the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) - the numbers that are in one of the arrays, but not both:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
const arr2 = [2, 3, 4]

const result = _.xor(arr1, arr2)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```